"SwiftUI ignoresSafeArea Not Working with Keyboard in Custom Chat View"
I'm building a chat interface in SwiftUI where the chatTopView, chatList, and chatBottomView need to properly adjust when the keyboard appears. However, I’m encountering an issue where the ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom) modifier doesn't seem to work as expected—the chatTopView still shifts upward with the keyboard instead of remaining fixed.
var body: some View {
GeometryReader { geometry in
    ZStack {
        Color("bgColor").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        
        VStack {
            chatTopview
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                chatList(messages: $messagesManager.messages, messagesManager: messagesManager)
                    .onAppear {
                        switch currentlyUsingFor {
                        case .operationDetails:
                            messagesManager.loadMessages(withId: mission_Id)
                        case .others:
                            messagesManager.loadMessages(withId: selectedChat?.mission_id ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                
                Spacer()
                
                chatBottomView(selectedMissionId: selectedChat?.mission_id ?? "")
                    .environmentObject(messagesManager)
                    .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: geometry.size.height) // Ensures the VStack uses all available height
    }
    .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
}
.navigationBarTitle("")
.navigationBarHidden(true)
}

How can I properly handle the keyboard appearance in SwiftUI so that chatTopView stays fixed while chatBottomView adjusts with the keyboard?

Your code doesn't seem to be reproducible, but I just answered a similar question here. Maybe it will help.
